# Design decision class with property ID: nullable or not

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture

I'm creating an object that would be used as POCOs for EF. What is more appropriate for property ID: nullable int or just int and having a value of zero if new. I was thinking that ID should be nullable.

When I pass this, I could check if data is new if ID is null. I thought this was appropriate because I think zero is a valid DB value. But I am not sure. Any suggestions/guidelines/drawbacks I can based my decision on?

Comment: This isn't really about EF. Just answer the question: *Can the value be null in my database, is a record valid with a null value for that column?* If so, make it nullable, otherwise don't.

Comment: If the database field is required then the property shouldn't be nullable. Especially the ID. If you want to know if an entity is new you should ask the database context and not interpret the ID value.

Comment: a value with an ID of null should (almost) never be in the database, so the column should be not nullable (unless you have other means of identifying an entity). For determining if an entry is new or not, you can use DateTime values, or, when it is only important if the entry is saved in the database or not, use 0 or negative values for ID (most Key columns will be autoincrement anyways, meaning there won't be valid entries with a PK of <=0)